# Why is this code failing to verify?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cil, peverify

I have a compiler that builds and runs correctly, but PEVerify is calling it unverifiable at a certain point.  After looking carefully at the error, the corresponding source code, and the ILDasm output for the point in question, I can't find the problem, to the point where I would suspect a bug in PEVerify, except that the .NET and Mono versions report the same error in the same place.

[The problematic method](https://github.com/boo-lang/boo/blob/master/src/Boo.Lang.Compiler/TypeSystem/Services/AsyncHelper.cs#L78) reads as follows:

```
internal static bool InAsyncMethod(Expression value)
{
    INodeWithBody ancestor = value.GetAncestor<BlockExpression>() ?? (INodeWithBody) value.GetAncestor<Method>();
    return ContextAnnotations.IsAsync(ancestor);
}
```

The error is reported as:

> [IL]: Error: [D:\SDL-1.3.0-4423\boo\build\Boo.Lang.Compiler.dll : Boo.Lang.Compiler.TypeSystem.AsyncHelper::InAsyncMethod][offset 0x00000011][found ref 'Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.Node'][expected ref Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.INodeWithBody'] Unexpected type on the stack.

Offsest `0x11` corresponds to the second half of the `??` expression.  From ILDasm:

```
.method assembly hidebysig static bool  InAsyncMethod(class Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.Expression 'value') cil managed
{
  // Code size       29 (0x1d)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.INodeWithBody ancestor,
           [1] bool CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  callvirt   instance !!0 Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.Node::GetAncestor<class Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.BlockExpression>()
  IL_0007:  dup
  IL_0008:  brtrue.s   IL_0011
  IL_000a:  pop
  IL_000b:  ldarg.0
  IL_000c:  callvirt   instance !!0 Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.Node::GetAncestor<class Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.Method>()
  IL_0011:  stloc.0
  IL_0012:  ldloc.0
  IL_0013:  call       bool Boo.Lang.Compiler.Steps.ContextAnnotations::IsAsync(class Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.INodeWithBody)
  IL_0018:  stloc.1
  IL_0019:  br.s       IL_001b
  IL_001b:  ldloc.1
  IL_001c:  ret
} // end of method AsyncHelper::InAsyncMethod
```

The `Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast.Node` class is the base class for all AST nodes.  `BlockExpression` and `Method` are the node classes for lambdas and methods, respectively, both of which implement the `INodeWithBody` interface.  Everything appears correct, both in the C# (which would not build if there were type problems) and in the IL (where it says at `000c` that the return type of the `GetAncestor<Method>` call is `!!0`, the first type parameter on the method call.)

What is causing PEVerify to think it's dealing with a value of type `Node` here when it clearly has a value of type `Method`?  And is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Having debugged a number of these myself over the years: it's almost always involving some version of the  `? :` conditional operator. The verifier has changed its strategy for dealing with conditionals over the years, and it can get quite confusing.

Comment: @EricLippert This time it was the `??` operator.  (See the accepted answer for details.)  Rewriting it as two separate statements fixed it, which is a bit odd as the code ought to be exactly equivalent.  I'm just surprised to see `csc` generating unverifiable IL!

Comment: The `??` operator is just the `?:` operator in fancy dress. (Similarly `&&` and `||` and `?.`)  If `csc` is generating this then either (1) your version of csc was tested against a different version of the verifier; as I said, its algorithm has changed over the years, or (2) csc has yet another freakin' bug in a conditional code path; please report it, glad I don't have to fix it this time, or (3) both.

Comment: @EricLippert This was in VS2013's C# compiler.  If I submit a bug report, will that do any good, or will the answer be "update to a newer version of Visual Studio"? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is causing PEVerify to think it's dealing with a value of type `Node` here when it clearly has a value of type `Method`?

As pointed out by Stephane Delcroix as well, there are two code paths reaching to `IL_0011`, as it is the target of a branch. It clearly does not necessarily have a value of type `Method`.

`GetAncestor<TAncestor>` returns `TAncestor`. You've got either `GetAncestor<BlockExpression>`'s result, or `GetAncestor<Method>`'s result, so either `BlockExpression` or `Method`. Both implement `INodeWithBody`, so logically, the code is still fine.

Unfortunately, "either `BlockExpression` or `Method`" is too much for verification. This gets simplified to `Node` (the common base), which does *not* implement `INodeWithBody`. See ECMA-335 §III.1.8.1.3:

> The merged type, `U`, shall be computed as follows (recall that `S := T` is the compatibility function defined in §III.1.8.1.2.2):
>
> 1. if `S := T` then `U=S`
> 2. Otherwise, if `T := S` then `U=T`
> 3. Otherwise, if `S` and `T` are both object types, then let `V` be the closest common supertype of `S` and `T` then `U=V`.
> 4. Otherwise, the merge shall fail.

If you check what the C# compiler does, you'll see that it emits a `stloc.0`/`ldloc.0` combination into a local of type `INodeWithBody` prior to the `dup`. This makes everything work, because the common type of `INodeWithBody` and `Method` is then `INodeWithBody`.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally missed that conditional jump!  Unfortunately, moving the cast to the other side of the ??, or even putting it on both, creates the same unverifiable IL.  Any idea how to fix this properly?  Or should this be reported as a bug in `csc`?

Comment: @MasonWheeler Wait -- you're getting this IL from csc? I thought you were getting this from your own compiler, sorry for misunderstanding. csc shouldn't be generating this, and in the last paragraph, I described the behaviour I saw from a C# compilation. You could try to install the Microsoft.Net.Compilers package to force a more up-to-date compiler to be used, and if that doesn't work, indeed, report it as a bug.

Comment: Yeah, this is coming out of the normal C# compiler in Visual Studio 2013.  Mono's C# compiler apparently generates the same problematic output.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if it fails on `0x11` due to the first or the right part of the `??` as `0x08` is branching to there.

I'm leaning toward thinking `GetAncestor<>` returns a `Node` and the left part of the `??` is missing an explicit cast.

Comment: This is a reasonable guess, but it turns out `GetAncestor<TAncestor>` returns `TAncestor`, and both `BlockExpression` and `Method` derive from `Node` and implement `INodeWithBody`.